# while loop doesn't stop looping even after variable change

Tags: python, while-loop, break

In my code I have to ask users some input. When a condition is met the program should stop running!

```
ALIVE = True

def you_died():
    global ALIVE
    ALIVE = False

def some_input():
    choice = input()
    if choice == "yes":
        you_died()

while ALIVE is True:
    some_input()
    print("some string")
```

Why is my code still printing "some string" even though the variable ALIVE is False?

How to break the loop from inside the function?

Comment: Don't write `while ALIVE is True:`  Just write `while ALIVE:`  Regarding your logic, it looks like it should print `some string` once after you enter `yes`, then exit the loop.

Comment: "some string" should not be printed if ALIVE = False

Comment: You may not want it to be printed, but it will be.  Look at your code.  The sequence is (1) it inputs "yes", and sets `ALIVE` to `False`, then (2) it prints `some string`, and (3) *THEN* it goes back to the top of the loop to check the value of `ALIVE`.  The check is not made until *AFTER* it prints `some string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While conditions are evaluated once per iteration so changing the variable that is used in the condition won't cause it to immediately break. Also, you can't `break` from within a function. BUT you CAN test your global after calling your function and break if it isn't true before performing any other steps in your while loop:

```
ALIVE = True

def you_died():
    global ALIVE
    ALIVE = False

def some_input():
    choice = input()
    if choice == "yes":
        you_died()

while ALIVE is True:
    some_input()
    if not ALIVE: break
    print("some string")
```

Comment: Note that using `while ALIVE is True` is redundant in this case; you can just make it `while True:` since if `ALIVE` is false the loop will be broken before it restarts anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Only `break` and exceptions can stop loops in the middle of execution. Otherwise, the current iteration will complete even if the condition is no longer true:

1. Check condition. It's `True`, so begin 1st iteration.
2. Call `some_input` which modifies `ALIVE`, so the condition isn't true anymore. However, it's not time to check the condition yet!
3. Run other statements of the loop, like `print(stuff)`
4. ...
5. Once there's no more code in the loop (the 1st iteration is done), check the condition again.
6. It's `False`, so stop the loop.

Basically, a loop is executed in the same manner that it's written:

1. Check condition. If `True`, `goto 2`. Otherwise skip the entire loop (`goto 4`).
2. Start executing the loop body (code that's within the loop).

   1. If stumbled upon a `break` statement, jump out of the current loop: `goto 4`.
   2. If there's an exception, interrupt everything we're doing and propagate the exception until it's handled somewhere. If it's not handled, stop execution entirely.
3. Once the loop body is executed, `goto 1`.
4. Execute code after the loop...

Answer (score 1):

You print `"some string"` after calling `some_input()`, before the loop restarts and `ALIVE` is checked, so there's no opportunity for the loop to decide not to repeat in between calling `some_input()` and doing the `print`.

A simple fix would be to call `some_input()` once before your loop starts, so that `ALIVE` is initialized with the result of the first `some_input()` call, and then call `some_input()` at the end of the loop (not the beginning) so that `ALIVE` is re-evaluated before you print again:

```
some_input()
while ALIVE:  # no need to say "is True"
    print("some string")
    some_input()
```

A better way to organize this code would be to have your function tell you if you died (via its return value, not a `global`), and `break` the loop immediately if so.  This allows you to use a simple `while True`, relying on the `break` to stop the loop at the appropriate time:

```
def you_died():
    """Asks for input, returns True if you died."""
    return input() == "yes"

while True:
    if you_died():
        break
    print("some string")
```

Comment: "some string" should not be printed! What I want to achieve is to break the loop if the condition is met

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do (or if I don't, your comment didn't improve my understanding).  Did you run the code I gave you?  It doesn't print anything if you enter "yes" immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `ALIVE` variable to `False`, will only stop the `while` statement of executing a new iteration.

If you want the `print("some string")` statement to only execute when the
user answers something other than "yes", with minimal changes to your current implementation, you can move the `print` to `some_input` like so:

```py
ALIVE = True

def you_died():
   global ALIVE
   ALIVE = False

def some_input():
   choice = input()
   if choice == "yes":
       you_died()
   else:
       print("some string")


while ALIVE is True:
   some_input()
```

However, I strongly advise you not to use this approach. Here's why:

1. **Global variables:** The use of global variables leads to hidden  side effects. For larger programs, it's easy to lose track of all the pieces of code that might be using and altering your `ALIVE` variable. In the long run, overuse of global variable will lead to an increase in complexity. Since you've defined the function, `you_died` to specifically handle the process of stopping your `while/loop` statement, you might want to maximize the pros of functions by defining an `alive` input parameter to it, changing it to `False` and returning its new value.
2. **"Yes" vs "yes":** would you like your program to stop the `while` statement, when the user answers "yes", or "YES", "Yes", and even "Yes!"? If so, perhaps changing `if choice == "yes":...` to something like `if "yes" in choice.lower():...` might be a more robust approach.

Taking into account both aforementioned points, here's a suggestion on how you might want to re-write your code:

```py
def some_input(case_insensitive: bool = True) -> bool:
    """Ask User for input, and return `True` if they answer something other than "yes".

    Parameters
    ----------
    case_insensitive: bool, default = True
        Whether to consider User's input case-sensitive or not, when checking
        looking for replies equal to "yes". For example, if `case_insensitive` is set to
        `True`, then the function considers "yes", "Yes", and "YES" as the same
        answer.
    
    Returns
    -------
    bool
        `True`, if User inputs anything that doesn't contain the word "yes".
    """
    choice = input()
    if case_insensitive:
        choice = choice.lower()
    return "yes" not in choice


# Only enters the while statement, if the user
# answers something other than "yes" (e.g., "no") 
while some_input():
    print("some string")
```